# Calling class (compiled java file) file from DB and execute it at run time on application server

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc, oracle11g

I have requirement that client want to keep the `.class` file as `Blob` in `oracle 11g` Database (Since the `.class` has the logic for finance batch and encryption , the client don't want to place it on app server).

My question is

Is it possible to have such functionality in application which retrieves the .class file (compiled java file) from DB and execute it when called ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They really want to store the class in the database, but load and run it from an external application/JVM? They don't want to [run the Java class within the database](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e10588/cheleven.htm)? That could be called from an external application. e.g. with a PL/SQL procedure wrapper, but guess it depends what the class will be doing.

Comment: In this case yes we need to store the .class file DB say if it is for batch we can run from DB itself (but again need to know how) and if it is related to encryption it needs to be executed on application side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to write a custom [java.lang.ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) that uses the bytes read from the database to define the class.

It'd look something like this:

```
public class DatabaseClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{
  private DataSource dataSource;

  public DatabaseClassLoader(ClassLoader parent, DataSource dataSource)
  {
    super(parent);
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    byte[] classDefinition = loadClassDefinition(name);

    if (classDefinition != null)
    {
      Class c = defineClass(name, classDefinition, 0, classDefinition.length);
      resolveClass(c);
      return c;
    }
    else
    {
      return super.loadClass(name);
    }
  }

  private byte[] loadClassDefinition(String name)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Where the `loadClassDefinition` tries to load the bytes that represent the class using the name as the key in the SQL query - you'll have to define exactly how it does that yourself, but the outline would be, query the table, read the blob into an array and return it.

Comment: would it be possible for you share an example Thanks in advance